# ¿Cómo puedo arreglar este "StackOverflowError" en JAVA?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

He estado recibiendo un curso de Java, estoy atorado con un ejercicio relacionado con las interfaces (`JFrame`), ya que me tira el error "StackOverflowError" y no se porque... El codigo es el siguiente:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowFocusListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Ventana3_1 extends JFrame implements WindowFocusListener{

    Ventana3_1 m1 = new Ventana3_1();
    Ventana3_1 m2 = new Ventana3_1();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ventana3_1 miV = new Ventana3_1();

        miV.iniciar();
    }

    public void iniciar(){
        m1.setVisible(true);
        m1.setBounds(300, 100, 600, 350);
        m1.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        m1.addWindowFocusListener(this);

        m2.setVisible(true);
        m2.setBounds(1200, 100, 600, 350);  
        m2.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        m2.addWindowFocusListener(this);    
    }

    @Override
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tu código entra en una especie de bucle ya que cuando instancias el objeto **miV**  dentro de **main** el tipo de clase que usas es **Ventana3_1** pero a la vez esa misma clase instancia dos objetos de su mismo tipo llamados **m1** y **m2**.

En tu caso la manera mas sencilla de resolver el problema es no instanciar objetos de la clase **Ventana3_1** dentro de la misma clase así evitas caer en dicho ciclo infinito.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funcionó. El consejo que me darías es ¿hacer siempre el main en otra clase? o ¿colocar los objetos dentro de los metodos?